# Remote server: running a Python 2.7 script and making *.csv files publicly available

Tags: python, remote-server

I have a Python 2.7 script that produces *.csv files.  I'd like to run this Python script on a remote server and make the *.csv files publicly available to read.

Can this be done on Heroku?  I've gone through the tutorial, but it seems to be geared towards people who want to create a whole web site.

If Heroku isn't the solution for me, what are the alternatives?  I tried Google App Engine, but it requires Python 2.5 and won't work with 2.7.

MORE DETAILS:
I have a Python 2.7 script that analyzes all stocks that trade on the AMEX, NYSE, and NASDAQ exchanges and writes the output into *.csv files that can be read with a spreadsheet application.  I want the script to automatically run every night on a remote server, and I want the *.csv files it produces to be publicly available.

Comment: App Engine hasn't been Python 2.5-only for quite a long time. The 2.7 runtime is even the recommended one now.

Comment: It's really not hard to have your files be publicly available, just have that information written to a file on your webserver and make sure people have the URL to access it, one way or antoher.  A csv is just text, so you can even literally have a webpage that has the comma-separated values on it that people ingest, if you need to.  I'm not quite sure what your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

**Web hosting**

Ok so you should be able to achieve what you need pretty simply. There are many webhosts that have python support. Your requirement is pretty simple. Just upload your python scripts to the web server. Then you can schedule a cron job to call your script at a specific time every day. Your script will run as scheduled and should save the csv files in the web servers document root. Keep in mind you don't need to your script to run in the web server, just on the same server. The web server will just serve your static csv files for you once you place them in the webserver's document root.

**Desktop with dropbox**

Another maybe easier option is take any desktop and schedule your python script to run on it each night you can do this in windows, Linux, Mac. Also install [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) it gives you 2GB free online storage. Then your scripts just have to save the csv fies to the  Dropbox/Public directory. When they do this they will automatically get synced to the dropbox servers and can be accessed through your public url like any other web page on the internet. You get 2GB for free which should be more then enough for a whole bunch of CSV files.